# How to disable a image to load through selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have tried the below code to disable the image that being loaded in a page.

```
      public DesiredCapabilities setDesiredCapabilities() throws ExpectedException {
         FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
         profile.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
         profile.setPreference("permissions.default.stylesheet", 2);
         DesiredCapabilities desired = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
         desired.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
         return desired;
      }
```

Also, I called this desire capabilities into firefoxDriver class file. But the problem is that its not realize the image profile settings and Its not disable the image in a page, but the remaining capabilities are working fine. like Its successfully disabled the css properties.

I used **about:config** to check the custom property is invoked in firefox. stylesheet shows custom property as expected. but image still shows default value.

Comment: You can try to call `JavaScript` execution in your code to delete element or change `CSS` `visibility` attribute value to `hidden`

Comment: I don't want to do this for specific image. I want to do this for all images. However, the same code may be repeated in all scripts. Is there any possibilities to invoke that into profile setting and called that only once?

Comment: You can apply it to `<image>` tag that will cover all images. But I guess code should be called every time after new page loaded

Comment: I can made single if and else condition to apply this changes when It executes in CI server (its easy when I did it in profile level). Locally people want to execute the scripts with image where its not required in CI box . Even my scripts won't do anything with image. if I call the scripts every new page Little bit hard to make it work in CI and not in local (laptop). However, many thanks for great suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want:

```
profile.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 1);
```

? Option [1](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/981640) is never load the images